# Date Format and CiviContribute/Data Form Confirmation Page

Tags: civicontribute, forms, localisation

We are using CiviCRM with the european portuguese language pack and during setup we set the date format to be dd.mm.yyyy at localisation/date format (administration tab).

We have created a civicontribute form/page where we request dates twice. Everything is fine in the way a user inserts the date and it shows the date in the preset date format we chose (e.g. 10.04.2015). However when you press "contribute" and advance to the confirmation page the dates don't show like that anymore but in the US format (04/10/2015). I am afraid this will generate a lot of confusion because people will think they have filled in the date incorrectly.

I've tried changing all possible date settings at civiCRM administration and nothing works. We simply can't use the form until this is fixed.

Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, the two date fields are custom fields included in a profile?

Comment: Hi bgm, one is a custom field (valid date of a document) and the other is not (birth date), both included in a profile. The output is the same with both.

Answer (score 3):

The bug come from QuickForm being used to render in "freeze" mode (read-only) for the contribution confirm page.

The bug had been reported here:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14588

I wrote a patch for it against CiviCRM 4.7 (master dev branch), but it should be easy to apply on 4.6:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5729

Could you test the patch to see if it fixes the issue? If you are not familiar with patches, you can download the file from the pull-request:
https://github.com/mlutfy/civicrm-core/blob/47-crm14588/CRM/Core/Form/Renderer.php

Then click on the "raw" link, which leads to:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlutfy/civicrm-core/47-crm14588/CRM/Core/Form/Renderer.php

You can then save this file and replace the file in your local CiviCRM installation.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is semi-related to this issue:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15973

Would be a great candidate for a patch contribution

Comment: See also: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14588